# How to find Onchange function of field in odoo 13

Tags: odoo

Hope my message finds you well,

I had inherited a odoo model (product.attribute) and also had overridden a field (display_type).

```
class darazProductAttributes(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.attribute"

    display_type = fields.Selection([
        ('text', 'Text'),
        ('radio', 'Radio'),
        ('select', 'Select'),
        ('color', 'Color')], default='radio', required=True, help="The display type used in the Product Configurator.")
```

i had added one more option (text) in field.Now the selection of option field it loads product.attribute.lines model form basically it have a onchange method.Odoo shows me that display_type have a onchange but odoo don't show method name.
[image]

So i want to override that function.

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can use `selection_add ` when inheriting a [selection field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/fields.py#L2031) to add only the new options

Comment: Please provide a list of installed custom modules.

Comment: @Kenly  i haven't installed any custom module .

Comment: And secondly my issue is only with the onchange method.

Answer (score 1):

Field can have more than one `onchange` method, all you have to do is look for methods that are decorated with `onchange`:

```
@api.onchange('your_field_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
journal_id= fields.Many2one(comodel="account",
                             string="journal",
                             required=True
                                )  
 @api.onchange('journal_id')
 # call function every change field journal_id:
    def _onchange_journal(self):
        if self.journal_id and self.journal_id.currency_id:
            new_currency = self.journal_id.currency_id
            if new_currency != self.currency_id:
                self.currency_id = new_currency
                self._onchange_currency()
```